# Form not submitting data

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a sign up form in html, but it's not submitting any data to the php file. Weird thing is, to me an exactly the same looking form on the same page does work and this one used to work. I probably somewhere changed something accidently.

The form:

```
<form action="http://test.com/register.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <fieldset>
    <div align="left">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" required class="span11" name="fUsername" id="Username" placeholder="username">

<label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" required class="span11" name="fPassword" id="Password" placeholder="password">

    <label>Retype password</label>
    <input type="password" required class="span11" name="fRetypepassword" id="Retypepassword" placeholder="retype password">

    <label>Phone number</label>
    <input type="text" required class="span11" name="fPhone" id="Phone" placeholder="+... international format">

    <label>E-Mail</label>
    <input type="email" required class="span11" name="fEmail" id="Email" placeholder="e-mail">
<br><br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Register</button>
  </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

The PHP:

```
$username = htmlspecialchars($_GET['fUsername']); 
$password=htmlspecialchars($_GET['fPassword']);
$passwordmatch=htmlspecialchars($_GET['fRetypepassword']);
$email=htmlspecialchars($_GET['fEmail']);
$phone=htmlspecialchars($_GET['fPhone']);

echo $username;
```

Answer (score 6):

The form is sending data with method POST but you are trying to read it from $_GET.

Try:-

```
$username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['fUsername']); 
$password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['fPassword']);
$passwordmatch = htmlspecialchars($_POST['fRetypepassword']);
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['fEmail']);
$phone = htmlspecialchars($_POST['fPhone']);
```

Comment: :o, I oversaw that, I knew I was staring at an easy fix! Thanks!! I'll accept your answer when they allow me to.